# How to install more than one package with only one command via Terminal?

Tags: installation, command-line

I would like to do like on Synaptic - when you mark all the packages you want to install - and install all packages I want with a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install package1 package2 package3 ...
```